# Show that every finite-dimensional topological vector subspace is closed.

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed topological vector space. Show the following:

(i) If $0\neq v \in X$, then $\{\alpha v:\alpha\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is closed.

(ii) If $Y$ is a closed vector subspace of $X$ and $w\in X-Y$, then $Y\cup \{\beta w:\beta \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is closed.

Please help me. I am stucked with this question in the book.

Comment: I can't start the proof. Please help.

Comment: Can you describe how you have proved, in any earlier setting, that some subset of a topological space is closed?

Comment: I am used to doing that $A$ is closed if $A^C$ is open.

Answer (score 3):

ii) follows from i) as union of 2 closed sets is closed.

Hint for i) note that {x} is a closed set. Then try to use that scalar mult. is continuous. (You need the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete).